# Can you recommend a good calculus textbook that will help me prepare for physics?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, physics, mathematical-physics, education

I am a computer science student and i would like to start preparing myself for calculus and the physics classes that i will be taking over the next two years.Much like the question states, i am looking for a calculus textbook that is associated with how we take mathematical concepts and allocate them to physics.I'm currently looking into , "Calculus: An Intuitive and Physical Approach" by Morris Kline but i'm open to other suggestions that you all could provide me along with any reference material that could help in my educational pursuit.

Comment: Are you a college student or a high school student?

Comment: I'm a college student.Sorry, i should have stated that.I'm currently taking precalculus and would like to set myself up with material to study calculus throughout the summer.

Comment: I think it is best that you read the cal textbook that your college uses. It will prepare you for the calculus sequence. Once you have a good calculus background, I think it's much easier to learn physics then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned personally best through a combination of Stewart's Calculus alongside Spivak's Calculus. This really helped me get a fuller understanding of calculus. I struggled through electricity in my first year of physics because I didn't have a thorough understanding of calculus and these book's really helped. Also, I would use youtube as a huge resource in helping you understanding topics.

Answer (score 1):

For the textbook, I will suggest you to ask your college teachers which one to use.  As far as application of calculus in physics is concerned, take a look at the essence of calculus series on this channel https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw

It is really very helpful to get the basic understanding of calculus and its application.